# What status code should server respond with when status of completed asynchronous DELETE operation is requested?

Tags: rest, http-status-codes

Assume server responds with `202 ACCEPTED` to DELETE request and sets `Location` header to `\status\1`, where progress can be tracked. While the request is being processed, `200 OK` is returned for GET `\status\1` with some info in response body. What should server respond when deletion is done? Should it return `404 NOT FOUND` or should it return some other code indicating deleting was finished and preserve old statuses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a separate endpoint for the 'status of the operation', I would probably expect that endpoint to always return `200 OK` with more information.

404 returning from that endpoint doesn't tell me that the original DELETE has succeeded, but it tells me that the 'status itself' is removed.